# How can I start using variable outside $.get() function?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

```
var userIdD = $.get('http://someurl.com/options.php', function(abc) {
  var abc = $(abc);
  var link = $(abc).find('a:contains(View My Profile)');
  //console.log (link);
  var userID = $(link).attr('href');
  var userId = $(userID);
  console.log(userId);
  console.log(userID);
});

console.log(userIdD);
console.log(userId);
```

I can`t start using variables "userIdD" & "userId" outside function "abc".
Inside it, it works greatly.
Can someone help me to use them outside it? where I'm wrong?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I return the response from an asynchronous call?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call)

Answer (score 0):

Declare your variables outside the function:

```
var userID, userId;
var userIdD = $.get('http://someurl.com/options.php', function(abc) {
    var abc = $(abc)
    var link = $(abc).find('a:contains(View My Profile)')
    //console.log (link)
    userID = $(link).attr('href');
    userId = $(userID)
    console.log(userId)
    console.log(userID)
})
console.log(userIdD)
console.log(userId)
```

Comment: it still returns value of variable "undefined", and also appears 
"c.extend.ajax jquery-1.4.2.min.js:130
c.extend.get jquery-1.4.2.min.js:122
(anonymous function)"
errors

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that `userIdD` is set *asynchronously*. The stuff that happens inside the function call happens *after* the stuff outside the function call.

Here's a simplified example which you can run:

```js
$.get('http://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com', function(){
   alert('Stuff inside function happening');
});

alert('Stuff outside function happening');
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Now, if we look at your code, we'll see that you're trying to console.log variables that are set *inside* the function call.

To go around the asynchronicity, you can make use of promises. Let's have a look at how that works...

```js
var valuesPromise = $.get('http://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com').then(function(serverResponse){
  return { objectId: 123 }; // return stuff you want to use later
});

// later in your code, you can make use of the returned value...

valuesPromise.then(function(returnedValue){
  alert(returnedValue.objectId); // alerts '123'
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: It doesn`t helps me... It takes another error "TypeError: Object #<XMLHttpRequest> has no method 'then'"
U can look code I`ve made upper